# SATA drivers for Lenovo 3000 Y500

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, sata, lenovo-laptop

I tried to install WindowsXP via USB drive as DVD ROM isn't working on my notebook anymore, but the setup stuck at copying files after partitioning the disk. I googled and found out that I must integrate SATA drivers into the setup using nLite.

Now, my trouble is that I am unable to find suitable SATA drivers, searched a lot without any luck.

Contacted Lenovo support, but they have no clue. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Trick was to format USB in FAT16 LBA mode, I was using WintoFlash to make drive bootable.